# How to get collection that Filter by layer navigation?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
$rows = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
echo "Total Parameter : ".count($rows);
print_r($rows);
$para = count($rows);
if ($para == 2) 
{
     $arr1 = $rows[0];
     $arr_first_param = explode("=",$arr1);
     $arr2 = $rows[1];
     $arr_second_param = explode("=",$arr2);
     $ProductCollection = $category->getProductCollection()->addFieldToFilter($arr_first_param[0],['eq' => $arr_first_param[1]])->addFieldToFilter($arr_second_param[0],['eq' => $arr_second_param[1]]);
}
$products=$objectManager->create('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock');
$products->addInStockFilterToCollection($ProductCollection);
$count = count($ProductCollection);
echo $count;
```

Comment: Jayesh, Can U please clarify what extract you want?

Comment: when i filter collection by clicking on any option from layered navigation magento displays filtered collection , i want count of that filterd product collection .